# Arraylist - String/Double

Tags: java, string, arraylist, double

I am taking a basic objects first with java class, i don't know much yet and need a little help ..
I need to assign these values to an arraylist but also need to allow the user to choose a health option based on a string that will then output the value related to the option..

```
double [] healthBenDesig = new double [5];
double [] healthBenDesig = {0.00, 311.87, 592.56, 717.30, 882.60};
```

Strings I want to assign are:

```
none = 0.00
employeeOnly = 311.87
spouse = 592.56
children = 717.30
kids = 882.60
```

Ultimately, I want the user to input for example "none" and the output will relate none to the value held in the arraylist [0] slot and return that value. Is this possible? Or is there an easier way I am overlooking?

if anyone could help me out I would really appreciate it :) 
Thanks

Comment: You are gonna want to look into using a Map

Comment: If the values are compile time constants then use an `enum` to store them. Otherwise use a `Map`.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. This is possible with `HashMap`.

```
HashMap<String,Double> healthMap = new HashMap<String,Double>();
healthMap.put("none",0.00);
healthMap.put("employeeOnly",311.87);
healthMap.put("spouse",592.56);
healthMap.put("children",717.30);
healthMap.put("kids",882.60);
```

Now, when user enters `none` then use `get()` method on `healthMap` to get the value.

For safety check that key exists in map using `containsKey()` method.

```
if(healthMap.containsKey("none")) {
   Double healthVal = healthMap.get("none"); //it will return Double value
} else {
  //show you have entered wrong input
}
```

### See also

- [HashMap oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is `Map<String, Double>`.

```
Map<String,Double> map=new HashMap<>();
map.put("none",0.0);
```

Now when you want the value for "none" you can use `get()` method

```
map.get("none") // will return 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something for you to get started with since it's the assignment:

1. Create a `Map<String, Double>` that holds the number and string as key/value pair.
2. Store the above values into the map
3. When a user enters the input, capture it using Scanner
4. Do something like this.

   ```
   if(map.containsKey(input)) {
        value = map.get(input);
   }
   ```

Comment: Why lookup in the map _twice_? `containsKey` has a special usage related to `null` values mapped to keys. Here you can just `get` and then check for `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Map Inteface

```
Map<String, Double> healthBenDesig =new HashMap<String, Double>();
healthBenDesig.put("none", 0.00);
healthBenDesig.put("employeeOnly", 311.87);
healthBenDesig.put("spouse", 592.56);
healthBenDesig.put("children", 717.30);
healthBenDesig.put("kids", 882.60);

System.out.println(healthBenDesig);
```

**OutPut**

```
{
none = 0.0, 
spouse = 592.56, 
children = 717.3, 
kids = 882.6, 
employeeOnly = 311.87
}
```